# DVD presence not detected until after Windows Update

Tags: windows-7, video, dvd, video-encoding

I am running Windows 7 with Power DVD.

I had a couple of DVDs and I googled to find that *The Dark Knight Rises* is particularly a frequent evidence the issue.

When I insert the DVD into the drive, Windows File Explorer (as well as Cubic Explorer) would say the drive is empty.

However, Roxio would detect the DVD and even show the title of the DVD (The Dark Knight Rises). When I click on [Play] on the Roxio menu, Media Player (using Power DVD as decoder) would respond that Media Player is unable to play the DVD because of the encoding.

I decided to perform a Windows Update, after which the DVD was recognised and Media Player/Power DVD was able to play it.

I went to Microsoft site, which informs me that this problem only afflicts Vista and XP and leads me with links to download decoders for Vista and XP, while informing me that Windows 7 does not require those decoder downloads.

However, I also read the DVDs like *The Dark Knight Rises* employs a new scheme of anti-rip format.

My Questions:

1. What is that format or encoding and what are its dynamics?
2. Did running Windows Update fix the problem? Or did restarting (required by the update) fix it?
3. Is it a known issue?

There was *Mr and Mrs Smith* which also had nearly the same problem, but which required me to continuously to wobble my laptop (and hence the DVD drive) in order for the smooth playing of the movie. What was that about? Is that a different formatting from *Dark Knight*?

How many of these deviant formats are out there in the DVD jungle anyway?

Comment: This is to be expected.  The codec was likely updated.  DRM located on this disk are updated.  **You can determine the encoding of the disk yourself.**  You tell us that and we can explain the reason Media Player wasn't able to play it without an update.

Comment: I have returned Mr/Mrs Smith, WW Z, and Dark Knight and a Dark Knight replacement to Netflix. I am hoping someone who had investigated the Dark Knight issue could use it as an example to explain what is happening.